# Find Local Admins from Remote PC in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a Domain User account and I want to, natively and in an easy way, find out the local administrators of a remote computer.

I am trying 3 ways:

1)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTE_PC -ScriptBlock{Get-LocalGroupMember -Name 'Administrators'}
```

Problem: I cannot connect because winRM is probably not allowed, so this method cannot be used.

2)

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group  -ComputerName REMOTE_PC
```

Problem: I get all the groups, not only the administrators

3)

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group -Filter "LocalAccount=true" -ComputerName REMOTE_PC
```

Problem: I only get LocalAccounts

4)

```
Invoke-EnumerateLocalAdmins -Hosts REMOTE_PC
```

Problem: I get the PCs but it is not a native way to do it (it is from the Powerview suite)

I guess there must some filter Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group that I am missing.

By the way, another question:

When asking for that, the retrieved information is only the local and domain administrators of the machine from the GPO Policy, no the ones **pushed** locally into the machine right? For that you need local admin in the machine right?

Comment: That is a good one, but I wanted to do it without Local Administrator privileges on the remote machine.

Comment: Erm. It's using the exact same command (Get-WMIObject) and permissions as your script....

Comment: That why I was looking for alternatives, this would be the answer to my question after some deep research: `([ADSI]"WinNT://<SERVER>/Administrators").psbase.Invoke('Members') | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}`

Comment: That still requires permission on the target machine. And it wasn;t the question you asked.

Comment: By default newer systems only allow Administrators (beginning with Windows 10 version 1607 and Windows Server 2016).
Older systems allow **any Authenticated User**